# jQuery templates and partial views

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-templates

I have an ASP.NET MVC 2 website that I am starting to use [jQuery Templates](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/) on. I love them and they work great, but I am trying to add this to a listing that contains a partial view. I know they effectively solve the same issue, except that I need both.

```
<script id="ListingTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <div>
        <% Html.RenderPartial("Listing", {{ID}}); %>
    </div>
</script>
```

This fails as `{{ID}}` is not an ASP.NET variable and I cannot find a way to get this to resolve. I would like to use a workflow like this rather than attempt to rewrite my partial logic in JS.

Comment: What is `ID`? Are you trying to assign an id to the template?

Comment: Yes, and ID from the data returned by AJAX call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jquery templates run on the client side. `Html.RenderPartial` on the server, much before any client side code has the chance to execute. The whole purpose of jquery templates is not to use any server side html, but to define the template purely on the client side.

Comment: OK, but I am appending this via a jQuery AJAX call. Still no way to tie these together?

Comment: @Dustin Laine, in the success callback of your AJAX call simply run the template execution by passing it the returned JSON (I presume?) object from your server. No partials. You no longer need any partial views if you are using a javascript templating engine such as jquery templates as it is now this engine that is supposed to generate the markup. You no longer define the markup on your server partials.

Comment: I second @Darin. Sending both the markup and data defeats the purpose of jQuery templates.